# How to make background window not appear while executing powershell script

Tags: user-interface, powershell, executable

Whenever i execute the gui powershell script, in addition to gui form , the background window(a command window) appears; how to eliminate that , should i execute the script in any different way?

-> please do let me know if any additional questions regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try create a shortcut calling the script with the `-windowstyle` parameter:

```
powershell.exe -sta -WindowStyle Hidden ".\myGUIscript.ps1"
```

This run powershell console then close it but let the GUI contiune his job